# Set default "iPhone Developer" certificate to be selected in "Automatic Profile Selector" in XCode/Keychain

Tags: ios, xcode

At my company, we have two separate developer portals, one for internal/BD apps, and one for external/contracted apps.  Because of that, I have two separate developer certificates.

I would like to keep it in XCode so that the "Code Signing Identity" is just set to "iPhone Developer", from the "Automatic Profile Selector" grouping (and not iPhone Developer: {Name} {ID}).  Obviously having it hard-coded to my name and specific key is highly undesirable on a project with multiple people.

However, certain iPads are only provisioned for one of the two portals, so the default 'iPhone Developer' certificate is only valid about half the time, depending on the project (and if I do a "refresh" on certs in Organizer, all bets are off on which one will become associated as the default "iPhone Developer").

Have had a tough time finding good solutions for this.  Anyone know how to change which certificate key is associated with the generic "iPhone Developer" entry?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this a common issue too, but as far as I understand it, the defaults are chosen based on which profile is most appropriate for the app you are working on. This seems to be done according to the bundle identifier associated with each profile - the profile with an applicable bundle identifier is chosen as the automatic selection, with a preference towards a more distant profile expiry date.

Of course, this decision is not based on the device you intend to run the app on, which means the wrong profile is often chosen,which leads to great frustration on the part of the developer who then has to change the profile to a static setting and always remember to change back before committing their changes (or more often forget, causing even more frustration for the other members of the team!)

PS: If anyone else knows differently here, I'd love to know how its done!

Comment: Most distant expiry date - Is that really the mechanism that Xcode uses? It would be nice if Apple documented this somewhere.  Does it take other entitlements into consideration - for example need for Push notifications?

Comment: @AneilMallavarapu: I'm afraid I'm really not sure. I would like to think that other entitlements were taken into consideration, but since I have no direct experience, I wouldn't like to comment :)